# Issue with ngFor not displaying new data pushed to the source array

Tags: angular, typescript, signalr

I'm having a strange issue with an ngFor when new data is added to the source array. For some reason the new elements are added the DOM but seem to be immediately removed. I can only get them to appear intially by using the ChangeDetector's detectChanges method. Interestingly the element is visible for an extended period of time when I run it in production mode. I've debugged all of my components to ensure they aren't being reloaded and also debugged any calls to my API to ensure the data isn't being fetched again thus effectively removing the data just added. The data seems to be removed from the source array which seems to be the root cause of the problem, unsure why it would remove that specific entry immediately after adding it.

The new data is sent to the application as part of a signalR event so unsure if this could have any correlation. I'm assuming it's an issue in my own logic somewhere but unsure of anything that could be causing it.

The data is added to the boardEntries array in the BoardColumnComponent.

```
BoardColumnComponent.ts


export class BoardColumnComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() columnIndex: number;
@Input() columnData: BoardColumnModel;
@Input() boardEntries: Array<BoardEntryModel>;

backgroundColour: string;

constructor(private signalEventsService: SignalEventsService,
            private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef,
            private applicationRef: ApplicationRef) { }

ngOnInit() {
    console.log ("Column Init")
    this.backgroundColour = BoardColours[this.columnIndex];

    this.signalEventsService.boardDataEventEmitter.subscribe(res => {
        var boardEntryModel = new BoardEntryModel();
        Object.assign(boardEntryModel, res);

        if (boardEntryModel.ColumnIndex == this.columnIndex) {
            this.boardEntries.push(boardEntryModel);
            this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
        }
    });
}
```

Here's the HTML

```
board-column.component.html


<div class="board-column" [style.background-color]="backgroundColour">
    <div class="board-column-header">
        <h3>{{ columnData.ColumnName }}</h3>
    </div>
    <app-board-entry *ngFor="let boardEntry of boardEntries" [boardEntry]="boardEntry"></app-board-entry>
</div>
```

And the board-entry.component.ts

```
export class BoardEntryComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() boardEntry: BoardEntryModel;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log ("Entry Init")
    }
}
```

And the board-entry.component.html

```
<div class="board-entry-container">
    <p>{{ boardEntry.EntryContent }}</p>
</div>
```

I can add anymore code necessary, any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

firstly if you are always getting the `res` of type `BoardEntryModel`, then you can just add the data type that is expected for your `res`. That means add `res:BoardEntryModel`. After adding this you don't need to initialize the new object every time.

And maybe according to your logic implemented, the subscription is called again once the data gets injected.

Thus before adding data to the array, just add the condition `if(res)`, so when there would be nothing caught, it would just skip the further steps.

So can you try to update your .ts file with the following code:

```
   export class BoardColumnComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() columnIndex: number;
@Input() columnData: BoardColumnModel;
@Input() boardEntries: Array<BoardEntryModel>;

backgroundColour: string;

constructor(private signalEventsService: SignalEventsService,
            private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef,
            private applicationRef: ApplicationRef) { }

ngOnInit() {
    console.log ("Column Init")
    this.backgroundColour = BoardColours[this.columnIndex];

    this.signalEventsService.boardDataEventEmitter.subscribe((res:BoardEntryModel)=> {
          if(res){
        // var boardEntryModel = new BoardEntryModel();
        // Object.assign(boardEntryModel, res); 

        if (res.ColumnIndex == this.columnIndex) {
            this.boardEntries.push(res);
            this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
        }}
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the casting, unfortunately it still seems to be removed from the DOM immediately, the array also seems to be missing the new data once the element disappears too so it seems to be a problem with the array

Comment: So there might be some other code which gets the array updated. Please check the code by keeping the debug points on all the lines where you have used this array.

Answer (score 0):

I've been unable to track down the reason for the component reloading so I've moved the SignalR subscription logic into the parent logic and it's working for now, thanks for the help